# Tag family feature?

Tags: feature-request, tags

I don't really want have to micro manage my tag subscriptions. Is is possible to have some kind of tag family where I can subscribe to the family tag and then get all of the related tags? I don't really mean synonyms, but more topics which are closely related and can be considered variations on a theme. I know that there's already tags at these levels, but they don't seem to include questions with related, more specific tags.

For example: TFS and Maven both are build systems and as such, part of the software development life cycle. There's tags for both of them. Some day there might be a new system. I'd like to be able to get notifications on both with a subscription to a higher level tag.

Comment: Bunch of related FR on Meta.StackExchange: [Ignore family of tags?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152224), [If I ignore you, the root Tag, I want to ignore your whole family](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105413), [Make 'Ignored Tags' a little more encompassing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177233), ...

Comment: ... [A proposal for tag hierarchy on SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/45438), [Implicit tagging hierarchy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58073), [Tag hierarchy to browse through tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6514), [Tag hierarchy absence - design reasons?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/45377), [Another kind of tag hierarchy/relationship](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59309)

Comment: I guess I have posted this in the wrong meta

Comment: I feel your pain. I have tag subscriptions for agile, scrum, cmmi, extreme-programming, waterfall, kanban, rad, personal-software-process, lean, and iso along with development-process. All of these are tags related to process and methods, and I need to watch to see if a new process-related tag appears. It can be painful. But tag hierarchies have consistently been declined by the development team. And let's not even get into multiple groupings (I also follow project management related tags) or cross-site usage of tags where someone asks a question I am interested in on a different site.